# How to replace all newline and tab charcaters with their respective \x code using php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, replace

Hello I want to replace all newline characters and tab characters with **\n** and **\t** respectively.

Consider the following code markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

After replacement the code should look like this

```
<!doctype html>\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\t\t<title>Test</title>\n\n\t\t\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t\n\t</body>\n</html>
```

How to achieve this?

and the also can we reverse this process? i.e can we get back the original form. If yes then How???

Comment: try looking at str_replace or preg_replace functions

Comment: Yeah for sure... But how to apply them???

Comment: $v="abc<br/>d"; $v=str_replace("<br/>","\r\n",$v);

Comment: but there is no `br` tag in the markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"), array('\n', '\t', '\r'), $html);
```

Comment: can we get the original string again

Comment: If you mean converting it back, try this: `str_replace(array('\n', '\t', '\r'), array("\n", "\t", "\r"), $html);`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this

```
 <?php
       $str = '
       <!doctype html>
        <html>
           <head>
              <title>Test</title>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
           </head>
           <body>
           </body>
        </html>
       ';

       echo $str;
       $arr = array("\n","\t","\r");
       echo $str = str_replace($arr, "", $str);
    ?>
```

// output -  `<!doctype html><html>   <head>      <title>Test</title>      <meta charset="UTF-8">   </head>   <body>   </body></html>`

Comment: No, after replacement i want `\n`, `\t`, `\r` character to appear.